# Help with this JOIN

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

```
$threads = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title
                        FROM threads t LEFT JOIN comments c ON t.id = c.parentID
                        ORDER BY c.date DESC");

while ($thread = mysql_fetch_assoc($threads)) {

 echo "<li><a href=\"?threadID=$thread[id]\">".htmlspecialchars($thread['title'])."</a></li>\n";

}
```

Can anyone see a problem in this code? It wont work as i want it. I want it the thread that was commented in latest on top, and the the next latest etc.

echo $thread[parentID] echoes nothing

comments:
id, comment, parentID, date

Comment: threads definitely has items? I usually do the full LEFT OUTER JOIN as well

Comment: yes i have bunch of threads and comments

Comment: @OP: Could you clarify the "It won't work as I want it" portion?

Comment: look again Eric, m english is not so good but i hope you understand

Comment: If some of your threads have no comments (btw, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN would have the exact same effect in this SELECT statement), you comments.date would be NULL and due do DESC sorting order those threads will always be LAST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ordering by a column not in your `DISTINCT` list.

This is valid syntax in `MySQL`, however this `ORDER BY` is meaningless.

This syntax is a [**`MySQL` extension**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), this query will fail in any other `RDBMS` engine of the big four.

It is used to simplify the `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` queries in the cases when same value of `column` in `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` always corresponds to same value of column in `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.

If your case, you can have multiple values of `c.date` for each value of `t.id`, and which value of `c.date` will be selected for `ORDER BY` is far from being guaranteed (it can be the last value, the first value or any other value).

Rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.title,
        (
        SELECT  c.date
        FROM    comments c
        WHERE   c.parent_id = t.id
        ORDER BY
                c.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) lastcomment
FROM    threads t
ORDER BY
        ISNULL(lastcomment), lastcomment
```

Comment: cant get this one to work. #1064 - ...use near 'ON c.parentID = t.id ORDER BY c.date DESC ' at line 5

Comment: `@Pryztojny`: fixed. It would be easier to check the syntax if you posted your tables definitions.

Comment: @Quassnoi - why are you saying ORDER BY on column not in select list is meaningless? It seems to work just fine for me in MySQL 5.0. Can you provide a link to documentation where this behavior is described?

Comment: @Quassnoi - thanks, but I'm very much aware that it's not standard SQL.  The question, though, was specific to MySQL and the reason your solution works in MySQL is not because of sub-select but because you're sorting by ISNULL() first :-) That said, it does work and it should also work in all ANSI-compliant DBs, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query in MySQL Query browser on your data, and see if this returns any results. If it does, then the issue is with your echo, not your query.

Comment: it does return but it wont order like i want it, the last commented thread on top

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used MySQL in awhile so this is something I know works in tSQL. You could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title
FROM threads t LEFT JOIN comments c ON t.id = c.parentID AND 
c.id = (SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM comments where comments.parentID = t.id)
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

This could easily get a bit slow with a lot of rows in comments. It might make some sense to store the last comment date in threads if you can if you notice a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked as what it sounds like you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title FROM threads AS t LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON t.id = c.parent_id ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

The only real thing that I changed was using

FROM threads **AS** T

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to echo the parentID, you need to include it in the query.

```
$threads = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title, c.parentID
                        FROM threads t LEFT JOIN comments c ON t.id = c.parentID
                        ORDER BY c.date DESC");
```